# Hibernate Inheritance:Table per concrete class with implicit polymorphism drawbacks or limitations

Tags: hibernate

I am not able to understand the limitations of implicit polymorphism in Hibernate

Please explain the points in bold.

(1) The main problem with this approach is, it doesn't support polymorphic association very well,  **All subclasses are mapped to different tables and polymorphic association to their superclass can not be represented as a simple foreign key.**

(2)  **Query against super class executes several SELECT statements (for every concrete class)  for polymorhic queries**.

(3) **A change to superclass properties effects the several columns of different tables in the database. It also makes it much more difficult to implement database integrity constraints that apply to all subclasses.**

If the Question is not clear,Please comment.

Comment: do you mean hibernate inheritance mapping?

Comment: yes,inheritance in hibernate..